# keys must be str, int, float, bool or None, not builtin_function_or_method

Tags: django, django-views

This is my cart views, im trying link my products/plans page to this view. Im trying to create an add to cart view so when i click add to cart it will go onto the cart page

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect, reverse

# Create your views here.

def view_cart(request):
    """ A view that renders the cart page """

    return render(request, 'cart/cart.html')

def add_to_cart(request, item_id):
    """ Add plan to shopping cart """
    
    cart = request.session.get('cart', {})
    cart[id] = cart.get(id, 1)

    request.session['cart'] = cart
    return redirect(reverse('plans'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your argument is `item_id`, but you're accidentally using [the builtin `id`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id):

```
def add_to_cart(request, item_id):
    # ...
    cart[id] = cart.get(id, 1)
    # ...
```

should be

```
def add_to_cart(request, item_id):
    # ...
    cart[item_id] = cart.get(item_id, 1)
    # ...
```

or

```
def add_to_cart(request, id):
    # ...
    cart[id] = cart.get(id, 1)
    # ...
```

Comment: Im now getting a NoReverseMatch, Reverse for 'add_to_cart' with arguments '('',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['cart/add/(?P<item_id>[^/]+)/$']

Comment: That can't come from the code you've posted, so it's a different question.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be in this line of code:

```
cart[id] = cart.get(id, 1)
```

Where is the "id" variable coming from? Did you mean `item_id`?

You are using the builtin `id` instead of `item_id`, so change it to:

```
cart[item_id] = cart.get(item_id, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

The *key* of the `add_to_cart` is a `item_id`, not `id`. This means that `id` is the builtin [**`id(…)`** function [Django-doc]](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#id). You thus should use `item_id` instead:

```
def add_to_cart(request, item_id):
    """ Add plan to shopping cart """
    
    cart = request.session.get('cart', {})
    cart[item_id] = cart.get(item_id, 1)

    request.session['cart'] = cart
    return redirect('plans')
```

That being said, normally requests that have side effects should be POST/PUT/PATCH/DELETE/… requests, not GET requests. Furthermore here you can only add the item once to the cart. If you want to add the item multiple times, you should alter the logic to:

```
def add_to_cart(request, item_id):
    """ Add plan to shopping cart """
    
    cart = request.session.get('cart', {})
    cart[item_id] = cart.get(item_id, 0) + 1

    request.session['cart'] = cart
    return redirect('plans')
```